# jruby on Rails : How to highlight the current navigation bar list item which the page user currently in

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm just trying jRuby on Rails for the first time.

In my project I'm having three pages under root/app/views/pages which I want to traverse in my navigation bar.

My navbar is

```
  <div class ="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li <%= class = is_active?("home") %> ><%= link_to 'Home', {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'home'} %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'About Us', {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'about'} %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Contact Us', {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'contact'} %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My CSS file contains

```
    .navbar .active {
           background-color: #4CAF50;
           color: white;
    }
```

After some googling i created a helper

```
   module PagesHelper
      def is_active?(page_name)
          "active" if params[:action] == page_name
      end
   end
```

in project_root/app/helpers/pages_helper.rb so that I would get highlighted in the navigation bar item based on the page I'm currently in.

This gave me

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected '='
...@output_buffer.append=( class = is_active?("home") );@output...
...                               ^
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:296:in `module_eval'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:296:in`compile'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:245:in `block (2 levels) in compile!'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in`instrument'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:244:in`block in compile!'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in `synchronize'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in`compile!'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in`instrument'

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In my navbar div I had to use "class = " out from the <%= %> like this.

```
    <ul>
        <li class = <%= is_active?("home") %> ><%= link_to 'Home', {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'home'} %></li>
        <li class = <%= is_active?("about") %>><%= link_to 'About Us', {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'about'} %></li>
        <li class = <%= is_active?("contact") %>><%= link_to 'Contact Us', {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'contact'} %></li>
    </ul>
```